# Update data on Android Application "Launch"

Tags: java, android, architecture

I'm looking for a best way to update my application on launch (get data from web-service). I want to show the progress on UI, issue is there are many activities, fragments, etc in my application and I don't know which of them is loaded on launch. For reasons I can't use **Services** so please don't suggest me that. I have extended **Application** class in my application if that helps.

Please suggest a proper way to do it on Android.

Comment: how do you not know which activity is launched on start ?

Comment: why you can not use Services?

Comment: Do you want that the data is updated when the application starts or when minimized to tray and maximze, too?

Comment: @Dante Exactly that is my issue I don't know which activity has started on re-launch.
Stefan: Is this not possible without services?
belyjz: I want to hit the server to check for update whenever my application is launched (by whatever way).

Answer (score -1):

Well if you have Application class, you always could override OnCreate method in it.

```
    public class MyApp extends Application {

       public void onCreate() {
           super.onCreate();
           Log.w("myApp", "OnCreate");

       }
    }
```

also you should say about created Application class in your manifest file.

```
    <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:name="com.example.myapplication.MyApp"
    android:debuggable="true">
```

Application OnCreate :

> Called when the application is starting, before any
>   activity, service, or receiver objects (excluding content providers)
>   have been created.

Comment: I did this but I also want to show the progress on UI. How to do that? How would I know which activity has started? Because user can be on any activity on relaunch of application.